# Is this Normal map correct

Tags: dictionary, 3d, 3ds, autodesk

[image: Normal map]

I want to know whether this normal map i created is correct.. I was expecting where the object is planar, it should have pure blue color, no component of red or green color... But clearly this is not pure blue. I created this using 3DS autodesk 2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it looks ok. Since the components of the normal is in the range `[-1, 1]` they need to be remapped to `[0, 255]` before they can be stored in the normal map. This is done by:

```
remapped = (value * 0.5 + 0.5) * 255
```

For a normal of `[0 1 0]` you get a value of `[128 255 128]`.